# How to convert a mkv file stream-wise if the stream encoding is rawvideo?

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

I am having an mkv file with three streams, two of them are rawvideo.

I can easly convert the one encoded in mjpeg using:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c copy -map 0:0 out.mp4
```

However, when I want to use it on the other streams with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c copy -map 0:1 out.mp4
```

I will get the error

> [mp4 @ 0000021ea068d200] Could not find tag for codec rawvideo in
>   stream #0, codec not currently supported in container Could not write
>   header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid
>   argument

When checking the documentation of FFmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) I was able to find out that rawvideo has no header, so I need to specify it manually, but how can I specifiy it manually during the conversion when reading it out of a mkv file?

Comment: MP4 does not support rawvideo, MOV does.

Comment: thank you, you want to give this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4 does not support uncompressed video, but Quicktime/MOV does

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c copy -map 0:1 out.mov
```